# Maximum number of elements in a set where all $k$ elements are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix $k\geq 1$ and a field $F$. Let's temporarily define a **good set** to be a subset $A\subseteq F^k$ satisfying:

1. $A\subseteq\{-1,0,1\}^k\subseteq F^k$, and
2. all subsets of $A$ having $k$ elements is linearly independent.

For example, $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,-1)\}\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is a good set, and $\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,1),(1,-1)\}\subseteq\mathbb R^2$ is not a good set.

My question is, what is the maximum number of elements that a good set can have? It is certainly greater than $k$ and less than $3^k$, since $\{(1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots,(0,\ldots,0,1),(1,\ldots,1)\}\subseteq \{-1,0,1\}^k$ is a good set, and (assuming $\operatorname{ch}F\neq 2$) there are $3^k-1$ nonzero elements in $\{-1,0,1\}^k$.